# doNotLinkIt in userFunc

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Im building my menu with the following typoscript

```
includeLibs.myadminmenu = typo3conf/ext/my_admin/user_makemenu.php
lib.userMenu = COA_INT
lib.userMenu.10 = HMENU
lib.userMenu.10 {
    special = directory
    special.value = 184
    modules = {$modules}
    entryLevel = 1
    1 = TMENU
    1.itemArrayProcFunc = user_myadminmenu->makemenu
    1 {
        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap = |
        ACT = 1
        ACT.allWrap = |
    }
}
```

This works fine, but inside my makemenu method I have the following

```
foreach($menuArr AS $i => $menu) {
    if (array_key_exists($menu['uid'], $this->paymentModules)) {
        if (! in_array($this->paymentModules[$menu['uid']], $modules)) {
            $menuArr[$i]['doNotLinkIt'] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesnt work - I have tried with

```
unset($menuArr[$i])
```

this removed the menu item, but I just want it to dont link, is there any way to do this?

If its not possible to unlink the menuitem, is it then possible to override the url to another page?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach could be:

(untested)

```
includeLibs.myadminmenu = typo3conf/ext/my_admin/user_makemenu.php
lib.userMenu = COA_INT
lib.userMenu.10 = HMENU
lib.userMenu.10 {
    special = directory
    special.value = 184
    modules = {$modules}
    entryLevel = 1
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap = |
        NO.doNotLinkIt = 1
        NO.doNotLinkIt.if {
          # the userfunc needs to return a list of pids like
          # value = 10,12,24,44
          value.postUserFunc = user_myadminmenu->makemenu
          isInList.field = uid
        }
        ACT = 1
        ACT.allWrap = |
        ACT.doNotLinkIt < .NO.doNotLinkIt
    }
}
```

IMHO this is easier to read and to maintain.